# Flutter - How to replace text (containing "id") with title for the id?

Tags: string, flutter, dart, replace

I have text like this:

Forecaster Strongly disagree \n\nSomething else is going to happen\n\nExample:-\n\n#:hashtag/424 \n#:hashtag/2818 ",

I need to get 424 and 2818 (which are ids) and find titles for those ids and replace #:hashtag/424 with #Title1

How do I manipulate string for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression like this:

```
  RegExp exp = RegExp(r'#:hashtag\/(\d+)');
  String test = "Forecaster Strongly disagree \n\nSomething else is going to happen\n\nExample:-\n\n#:hashtag/424 \n#:hashtag/2818";

  final matches = exp.allMatches(test);
  
  if(matches.isNotEmpty){
    print (matches.first[0]!.split('/').last);
  }
//prints 424
```

some additional null checks will probably be nececssary depending on what you can expect from the input string

To replace the IDs you could use the replaceAllMapped method like this:

```
  test.replaceAllMapped(exp, (match) => match[0]!.split('/').first + '/#Title1');
```